# Solving $ y' = \dfrac{2y}{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the diff. eq:

$$ y' = \dfrac{2y}{t}$$

I tried to do the following:

$$ y' = \dfrac{1}{t} \cdot 3y$$

$$3y = \dfrac{1}{t} \cdot y'$$

$$ \dfrac{3}{2} y^2 = \ln(t)$$

Here I stopped because I noticed the answer had to be $c \cdot t^3$. I don't understand how to get that answer.

Comment: After the first line the coefficient on the r.h.s. is 3...and you started with 2...

Comment: And a few lines further down, you claim that $t = 1/t$.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{y}{t^\color{red}{\alpha}}\right)'=\frac{y'}{t^\color{red}{\alpha}}-\frac{\color{red}{\alpha}}{t^{\color{red}{\alpha}+1}}y=\frac1{t^\color{red}{\alpha}}\left(y'-\frac{\color{red}{\alpha}y}t\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the separability of the variables.
$$y' = \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2y}{t}$$
We can use $dy$ and $dt$ as "normal" number, and we must move all "$y$"s on a side, and all "$t$"s on the other.
$$\frac{dy}{2y} = \frac{dt}{t}$$
Then, we integrate!
$$\int_{y(t_0)}^{y(t)}\frac{1}{2y} dy = \int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{1}{t}dt$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\log(y(t) - \log(y(t_0)) = \log(t) - \log(t_0)$$
$$\log(y(t)) = 2(\log(t) - \log(t_0)) + \log(y(t_0))$$
$$y(t) = e^{2(\log(t) - \log(t_0)) + \log(y(t_0))}$$
$$y(t) = e^{2\log(t)} e^{-2\log(t_0)}e^{\log(y(t_0))}$$
$$y(t) = \left(\frac{t}{t_0}\right)^2 y(t_0) $$

P.S. Don't know why in your second step, you have a "3" instead of a "2"...

Answer (score 0):

You can write the original O.D.E (I assume $y=y(t)$ is a $C^1$ function) as follows

$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{2}{t};$$

integrating both sides you arrive at

$$\ln y=2\ln(t)+C, $$

with $C$ constant. Then,

$$y(t)=C't^2,$$

as $2\ln t=\ln t^2$ and  $C'=e^C$.